# C: how to break apart a multi digit number into separate variables?

Tags: c, math, numbers, digits, digit

Say I have a multi-digit integer in C. I want to break it up into single-digit integers.

`123` would turn into `1`, `2`, and `3`.

How can I do this, especially if I don't know how many digits the integer has?

Comment: If your int started life as `char` data (input from user or text file ...) do not convert to int in the first place (no `scanf`, no `atoi` ...) and use the characters to separate the digits.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
int value = 123;
while (value > 0) {
 int digit = value % 10;
 // do something with digit
 value /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First, count the digits:

```
unsigned int count(unsigned int i) {
 unsigned int ret=1;
 while (i/=10) ret++;
 return ret;
}
```

Then, you can store them in an array:

```
unsigned int num=123; //for example
unsigned int dig=count(num);
char arr[dig];
while (dig--) {
 arr[dig]=num%10;
 num/=10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last digits of 123 is 123 % 10.
You can drop the last digit of 123 by doing 123/10 -- using integer division this will give you 12.
To answer your question about "how do I know how many digits you have" -- 
try doing it as described above and you will see how to know when to stop.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, getting the nth digit in the number is pretty easy; divide by 10 n times, then mod 10, or in C:

```
int nthdig(int n, int k){
     while(n--)
         k/=10;
     return k%10;
}
```

Comment: this is not nth digits, this is nth digits starting from the least significant

Comment: You don't consider the least significant digit to be the zeroth?

Comment: well, I consider first or zeroth digits of 123 to be 1, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think below piece of code will help....

```
temp = num;
while(temp)
{
    temp=temp/10;
    factor = factor*10;
}

printf("\n%d\n", factor);
printf("Each digits of given number are:\n");

while(factor>1)
{
    factor = factor/10;
    printf("%d\t",num/factor);
    i++;
    num = num % factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Based on Tony's answer
#include <stdio.h> 
int nthdig(int n, int k){
    while(n--)
        k/=10;
    return k%10;
}

int main() {
    int numberToSplit = 987;
    printf("Hundreds = %i\n",nthdig(2, numberToSplit));
    printf("Tens     = %i\n",nthdig(1, numberToSplit));
    printf("Units    = %i\n",nthdig(0, numberToSplit));
}
```

This results in the following printout:

Hundreds = 9

Tens     = 8

Units    = 7

Answer (score 0):

I made this based on the code from @asaelr:

```
typedef struct digitsArrayPlusNumber {
    uint32_t *baseAddress;
    uint32_t number;
} digitsArrayPlusNumber;

digitsArrayPlusNumber *splitDigits (uint32_t inValue) {
    // based on code from asaelr@stackoverflow.com

    uint32_t inputValue = inValue;

    //Count digits

    uint32_t theCount = 1;
    while (inputValue /= 10)
        theCount++;

    // put in array
    uint32_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * theCount);
    uint32_t dig = theCount;
    while (dig--) {
        arr[dig]=inValue % 10;
        inValue /= 10;
        //  printf ("%d\n", arr[dig]);
    }

    digitsArrayPlusNumber *dandn = malloc (sizeof(digitsArrayPlusNumber));

    dandn->baseAddress = arr;
    dandn->number = theCount;

    return dandn;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    for (int d = 0; d < splitDigits(12345678)->number; d++)
        printf ("%u\n", (splitDigits(12345678)->baseAddress)[d]);

}
```

It works quite well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use %10, which means the remainder if the number after you divided it. So `123 % 10` is 3, because the remainder is 3, substract the 3 from 123, then it is 120, then divide 120 with 10 which is 12. And do the same process.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //This is c#, but you can see how easy it would be to convert
        //to another language.

        int myNumber = 123456;
        string myWord = Convert.ToString(myNumber);

        string partOne = myWord.Substring(0, 2);
        string partTwo = myWord.Substring(2, 2);
        string partThree = myWord.Substring(4, 2);

        int num01 = Convert.ToInt32(partOne);
        int num02 = Convert.ToInt32(partTwo);
        int num03 = Convert.ToInt32(partThree);

        Console.WriteLine(num01);
        Console.WriteLine(num02);
        Console.WriteLine(num03);

        Output:
        12
        34
        56
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

we can use this program as a function with 3 arguments.Here in "while(a++<2)", 2 is the number of digits you need(can give as one argument)replace 2 with no of digits you need. Here we can use "z/=pow(10,6)" if we don't need last certain digits ,replace 6 by the no of digits you don't need(can give as another argument),and the third argument is the number you need to  break.

```
int main(){
long signed c=0,z,a=0,b=1,d=1;
scanf("%ld",&z);
while(a++<2){
       if(d++==1) 
       z/=pow(10,6);
       c+=(z%10)*b; 
       z/=10;
       b*=10;}
        return c;}
```

Comment: Never use pow for this

Answer (score -3):

You can divide and conquer but you have rewrite all of arithmetic libraries. I suggest using a multi-precision library https://gmplib.org But of course it is good practice