# How do you add the sum of digits in a chosen value range?

Tags: python, integer

I am trying to print every value between 100 and 999 whose integers add up to equal 7 using a  `for` or `while` loop in Python

Here is what I have so far, but once I have the three digits I don't know what to do.

```
three_digit = range(100,999,1)
dig1 = three_digit/10
dig2 = dig1/10
dig3 = dig1%10
lucky7 = (dig1+dig2+dig3)
print '' ,lucky7,
```

Comment: Where is your `for` or `while` loop?

Comment: that is where i am lost, i dont know how to make it work, im guessing its going to be while dig1+dig2+dig3 = 7: print three_digit ?

Comment: Open a python terminal and try to work through this interactively. In this case, you wouldn't get past the first line without running into errors. Read up on `for` loops and `if` statements. [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net) is a great resource.

Comment: thank you, i will look into this

Comment: Making the step (third) argument in your range explicitly set to 1 is unnecessary since 1-step is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow discourages coding everything for you, so here are some hints:

#### Break up a three digit number into single digits

Familiarize yourself with modulus (`%`) and floor division (`//`).  These will help you single out the digits in a number without having to convert it to a string.

#### Loops

You'll probably want to use a range-based `for` loop, which has the syntax of `for my_variable in range([enter your range])`.  Inside this loop you can add a condition (`if` statement) that prints out numbers that match your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

If you are free the create the loop yourself, there is no need to start converting values. Just use three loops to create all possible values.

```
for x in range(1, 10): # hundreds
   for y in range(0, 10): # tens
       for z in range(0,10): # ones
           if (x + y + z) == 7 :
               print (x,y,z)
```

gives

```
(1, 0, 6)
(1, 1, 5)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 3)
(1, 4, 2)
(1, 5, 1)
(1, 6, 0)
(2, 0, 5)
(2, 1, 4)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 2)
(2, 4, 1)
(2, 5, 0)
(3, 0, 4)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 2)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 4, 0)
(4, 0, 3)
(4, 1, 2)
(4, 2, 1)
(4, 3, 0)
(5, 0, 2)
(5, 1, 1)
(5, 2, 0)
(6, 0, 1)
(6, 1, 0)
(7, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dig1` is 2 digits, so it will always be more than 7 just on its own. For example 500/10 = 50.

Take a look at [this example (which is in c but should guide you)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302681/c-how-to-break-apart-a-multi-digit-number-into-separate-variables).

I think a simpler way is to stringify the number and then add up the int-ified digits:

```
for three_digit in range(100,999,1):
    digits = str(three_digit)
    sum_of_digits = (int(digits[0]) + int(digits[1]) + int(digits[2]))
    if sum_of_digits == 7:
        print (str(three_digit) + " is lucky")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of list comprehensions:

```
ans = [x for x in range(100,999) if sum([int(char) for char in str(x)])==7]
```

You can read about list comprehensions here: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk